# Calling the ImagePickerController (SourceTypeCamera) unloads other pages (other tabs) in tabbar controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uiimagepickercontroller

I have 2 tabs, one that contains the imagepicker controller, and another that contains a UItableView as a subview to a uiview controller.

I realise that when I call the imagepicker controller (SourceTypeCamera), my page in the other tab is being unloaded ('view didUnload' method) is triggered.

Is this a normal behaviour I should expect? (that other tab's views get unloaded) Or is it due to some memory issue when using the camera which I should take care off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, `viewDidUnload` can be triggered at any time, and is normally associated with a low memory warning, a view controller's view otherwise being cached even when not needed for as long as memory will allow. So in a strict sense it's neither expected nor unexpected, as it depends on the sum total state of the rest of the system.

That being said, `UIImagePickerController` is famously quite memory hungry when capturing an image (see e.g. [this image](http://blog.airsource.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/picture-2.png), where each spike is related to an instance of UIImagePickerController "capturing an image" per [the related blog](http://blog.airsource.co.uk/index.php/2008/11/12/memory-usage-in-uiimagepickercontroller/)), so other views being forced from memory shouldn't be so surprising.

There's no documented mechanism and no reason for a `UIImagePicker` to force other controllers to dump their views speculatively.

Comment: thanks for the great insight on this. So in other words I should not be too overly worried about this behaviour I guess?

Comment: No, anecdotal evidence suggests it's a common experience rather than the result of something you're doing incorrectly or poorly.